# Suggest app installation from Android browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, google-apps-marketplace

I need to put an iframe suggesting the installation of an app (which is on Google Play) if my webpage is opened from an Android browser.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if browser/system is android.
The following jQuery plugin may help: https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin

If it is android, set the iframe visible.

```
jQuery('iframe').show();
```